# How to Write a conditional statement in postman based on a value in an array

Tags: arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements, postman

Within each element in an array, there may or may not be a value that I need to grab.  If the value is not in one element, I want to go to the next element to look for it.  I'd like to know how to write the statement to do that in my Postman test.  I already know how to get the values when they exist, but I want to go through each element until I find what I'm looking for to put in the variable.

I've googled how to write the code, but I'm new to this and I'm having trouble.

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("Date", jsonData.array[0].field[1]);

if (postman.setGlobalVariable("Date", jsonData.array[0].field[1]) === ???
else (postman.setGlobalVariable("Date", jsonData.array[1].field[1]);)

Hi,  Here is a sample response (thanks!):  You can see the first element does not have the value, "NeedTheseDates" that I need to grab, but the second element does.

"SampleArray": [
        {
            "Date": "2019-05-18T00:00:00.0000000-04:00",
            "NeedTheseDates": [],
            "Anything": "data",
            "OnlyDate": "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000-04:00"
        },
        {
            "Date": "2019-06-16T00:00:00.0000000-04:00",
            "NeedTheseDates": [
                "2019-07-02T00:00:00.0000000-04:00",
                "2019-07-03T00:00:00.0000000-04:00",
                "2019-07-04T00:00:00.0000000-04:00",
                "2019-07-05T00:00:00.0000000-04:00",
                "2019-07-06T00:00:00.0000000-04:00",
                "2019-07-07T00:00:00.0000000-04:00",
                "2019-07-08T00:00:00.0000000-04:00",
                "2019-07-09T00:00:00.0000000-04:00",
                "2019-07-10T00:00:00.0000000-04:00",
                "2019-07-11T00:00:00.0000000-04:00",
                "2019-07-12T00:00:00.0000000-04:00"
            ],

Comment: Can you share a sample response? Also, what is max length of array and field?

Comment: Hi,  Here is a sample response (thanks!):  You can see the first element does not have the value that I need to grab, but the second element does.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure about the problem statement. So trying all combinations

## If there are only two cases where the value could be (index 0 or 1)

```
let someDate = jsonData.array[0].field[1] === '???' ? 
    jsonData.array[0].field[1] : jsonData.array[1].field[1];

postman.setGlobalVariable('Date', someDate);
```

## If the length of array is dynamic but the date you are looking for in field is always at index 1

```
let someDate;

jsonData.array.forEach((element) => {
  element.field[1] === '???' && (someDate = element.field[1]);
});

postman.setGlobalVariable('Date', someDate);
```

This will traverse all the items irrespective of whether it finds the correct element before. You can use `some` to stop that

```
let someDate;

jsonData.array.some((element) => {
  if (element.field[1] === '???') {
    someDate = element.field[1]);
    return true; // this will stop the loop
  }
});

postman.setGlobalVariable('Date', someDate);
```

## If the length of array is dynamic and field is also dynamic

```
let someDate;

jsonData.array.some((element) => {
  element.field.some((oneDate) => {
    if (oneDate === '???') {
      someDate = oneDate;
      return true; // this will stop the inner loop
    }
  });

  if (someDate) {
    return true; // this will stop the outer loop
  }
});

postman.setGlobalVariable('Date', someDate);
```